# How to hit a function of component on debounce time in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, observable, debouncing

How i set debounce time on component's function in angular.
Actually I hit a api from selectTableRow() method. when i select tr then hit api But when i select multiple tr then multiple requests are going to server.

I want when i select multiple table rows quickly then only send one request like (Autocomplete search).

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of tableData"
    (click)="selectTableRows($event, data)"
    [ngClass]="{'row-highlight': isRowSelected(data.id)}">
    <td>
        <span>{{data.name}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Method**

```
selectTableRows(event, rowData) {
    //Hit api from here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem use **debounce** method of lodash library.

```
npm i --save lodash
```

import **debounce** at the top of your .ts file

```
import {debounce} from 'lodash';
```

update your function like this:

```
  private debouncedFunction = null;
  selectTableRows(event, rowData) {
    if (this.debouncedFunction) {
      this.debouncedFunction.cancel();
    }

    this.debouncedFunction =  debounce(() => {
      console.log('selectTableRows', rowData);
      // make your API call here.
    }, 2000);
    this.debouncedFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: @lgor getting debounce() is undifined.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh, install lodash "npm i lodash", import debounce from lodash at the top of your .ts file "import {debounce} from 'lodash';

Answer (score 3):

here is the simple answer without using any library.

```
//define variable with null value
currentTimeout: any = null;

selectTableRows(event, rowData) {

    //put your logic here

    this.cancelTimeout();
    this.currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {

        // call api from here
    }, 1000);

}

cancelTimeout(): void {
    clearTimeout(this.currentTimeout);
    this.currentTimeout = undefined;
}
```

you can try this. And if you have any query then let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Its working for me without install any package.

Comment: after trying to implement debounce logic in various ways and failing, this simple logic did the trick for me.